# Multiplicative numbers used as a noun

Tags: grammatical-number

I got these following two example of multiplicative number **Zehnfache** used as a noun and possessing neuter gender, though I do not get much information on multiplicative number using as a noun. So my questions are, Are the all multiplicative numbers used as a noun? and which gender they possess?

> 1. … stiegen die Grundstückspreise zunächst aufs **Zehnfache**
> 2. das **Zehnfache** wert sein

Answer (score 3):

Yes, such *Multiplikatoren* are built all the same way, and they are all neutral:

> einhundertvierunddreißigtausend, das Einhundertvierunddreißigtausendfache
>
> das 134.000-fache *(often used, though not recommended)*

Sometimes, *Fugenlaute* are added:

> die Million, das Million**en**fache
>
> die Milliarde, das Milliarde**n**fache

And you can combine it with fractions, these are called *gemischte Zahl*:

> 5⅛, fünfeinachtel, das Fünfeinachtelfache.

In the case of 1½, you may hear

> 1½, *anderthalb, das Anderthalbfache*

That's a common replacement for the written

> 1½, eineinhalb, das Eineinhalbfache

Comment: FWIW, in Dutch, we also say **and write** *anderhalf* instead of *één en een half*.

Comment: The first letter of a noun needs to be capitalized.

Comment: A spelling error, I've corrected it.